# Как проверить наличие буквы в случайно выбранном слове?

Tags: javascript

Пишу игру Виселица. Идея такая: если игрок трижды вводит не правильную букву, происходит выход из игры. Внимание, вопрос: как проверить наличие вводимой буквы в рандомном слове?

```
let word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]; //Получаю  случайное слово//

let answerArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  answerArray[i] = '_';
}
let remainingLetters = word.length;
let failStep = 3;

while (remainingLetters > 0) {

  alert(answerArray.join(' '));
  let guess = prompt('Угадай животное ! Введи букву или нажми отмена для выхода из игры.');
  if (guess === null) {
    break;
  } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
    alert('Пожалуйста введите только одну букву!');
  } else {
    guess = guess.toLowerCase(); // Вводим только прописные буквы//
    for (let j = 0; j < word.length; j++) { // Обновляю состояние игры //
      if (word[j] === guess) {
        answerArray[j] = guess;
        remainingLetters--;
      }
    }
  }
  step--;
}
alert(answerArray.join(' '));
alert('Отлично ! Было загадано слово ' + word);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const isSymbol = (word, symbol) => word.includes(symbol) ? "Есть такая буква" : "Попробуй еще раз";

console.log(isSymbol("привет", "р"));
console.log(isSymbol("яблоко", "м"));
```